# Jsoup and thread error

Tags: android, multithreading, jsoup

I'm looking at jsoup libraries and i've write this simple code for watching how does it works:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    downloadThread.start();

}

Thread downloadThread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        TextView tw = (TextView) findViewById(R.text_view.tw1);
        Document doc;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.it").get();
            tw.setText(doc.title());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

And i've add this element to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

But when i launch software, i have the sequent error:

```
04-27 17:25:49.801: E/AndroidRuntime(26035): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2004
04-27 17:25:49.801: E/AndroidRuntime(26035):   
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that   
created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
04-27 17:25:49.801: E/AndroidRuntime(26035):    at   
android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4746)
04-27 17:25:49.801: E/AndroidRuntime(26035):    at   
android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:854)
04-27 17:25:49.801: E/AndroidRuntime(26035):    at  
android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4075)
04-27 17:25:49.801: E/AndroidRuntime(26035):    at  
android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10386)
04-27 17:25:49.801: E/AndroidRuntime(26035):    at  
android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10341)
04-27 17:25:49.801: E/AndroidRuntime(26035):    at  
android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6439)
04-27 17:25:49.801: E/AndroidRuntime(26035):    at    
android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3696)
04-27 17:25:49.801: E/AndroidRuntime(26035):    at  
android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3554)
04-27 17:25:49.801: E/AndroidRuntime(26035):    at 
android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3529)
04-27 17:25:49.801: E/AndroidRuntime(26035):    at 
com.example.webparsingtest.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:30)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access to UI components from threads different from the *main thread*.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new ExampleAsyncTask().execute();
    }

    static class ExampleAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... unused) {
            Document doc;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.it").get();
                return doc.title();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String title) {

            if(title == null){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            TextView tw = (TextView) findViewById(R.text_view.tw1);
            tw.setText(title);
        }
    }

}
```